# Getting JSON data for a Bootstrap Table from a Django server

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-table

I am trying to get data for the Bootstrap table from Django server as Json responce:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

    <table class="table table-striped" id="table"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data"
        #data-url="http://totoshick.pythonanywhere.com/getdata"
        data-side-pagination="server">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id">#</th>
                <th data-field="name">Report name</th>
                <th data-field="description">Description</th>
                <th data-field="link">Link</th>
                <th data-field="start_date">Last launch</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Data from Bootstrap Table [example](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/server-side-pagination.html): https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data

My data: http://totoshick.pythonanywhere.com/getdata

The table successfully shows the data from example, but not my ones - "No matching records found". Local varianat of my data:

```
{
  "total": 5,
  "totalNotFiltered": 5,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "description": "descr1",
      "link": "link1",
      "start_date": "2019-09-26T14:04:18Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2",
      "description": "descr2",
      "link": "link2",
      "start_date": "2019-09-26T14:04:37Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "name3",
      "description": "descr3",
      "link": "link3",
      "start_date": "2019-09-26T14:04:50Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "name4",
      "description": "descr4",
      "link": "link4",
      "start_date": "2019-09-26T14:05:30Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "name5",
      "description": "descr5",
      "link": "link5",
      "start_date": "2019-09-26T14:05:46Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Accroding to [documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#url) there are two types of json data BT work with. I have tried both variants (have not succeed), but my aim is server-side.

Django view.py code:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from .models import Report


def send_data(request):
    reports = Report.objects.all().order_by('start_date')
    serialized_queryset = {"total": reports.count(),
                           "totalNotFiltered": reports.count(),
                           "rows": []}
    for report in reports:
        temp = model_to_dict(report)
        serialized_queryset["rows"].append(temp)

    return JsonResponse(serialized_queryset, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2}, safe=False)
    #return JsonResponse(serialized_queryset["rows"], json_dumps_params={'indent': 2}, safe=False)
```

[Browser gets the json data correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kxys.png)

I have no idea where the problem is hidden beacuse json format from example is the same as my one. Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you posted performs a cross-domain request from JavaScript. Cross-domain requests are possible with CORS, which has to be supported by the server-side.

The example link supports CORS, your Django application does not. If you look in Chrome debug tools, you will see a corresponding error message.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I installed django-cors-headers and it works now.